# Representation of Uncertainty in linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a linear uncertain system represented by a family of models:

$\dot{x}=A_ix$,$i=1,\cdots,N$

I want to represent the system as:

$A_i=A_0+B\Delta_iC$

subject to the condition that $\lVert \Delta_i\rVert_2\leq 1$. Having $A_i$'s how should I find the $B$ and $C$? I find a solution in a paper, but I do not understand why they are following these steps. Can any one help me to understand why they follow these steps?
It goes like this:

Denote $\tilde{A}_i =A_i-A_0$. We must have:
$\tilde{A}_i\in Im B$ and $\tilde{A}_i^T \in ImC^T\, i=1,\dots, N$. 
Define new matrices:
$\Psi_B=\begin{bmatrix} \tilde{A}_1 &\tilde{A}_2\dots &\tilde{A}_N\end{bmatrix}$ and $\Psi_C=\begin{bmatrix} \tilde{A}_1^T &\tilde{A}_2^T\dots &\tilde{A}_N^T\end{bmatrix}$.Find the SVD of these matrices (why?):

$\Psi_B=U_B\Sigma_BV_B^T$ and $\Psi_C=U_C\Sigma_CV_C^T$. Denote $r_B=rank(\Psi_B)$ and $r_C=rank(\Psi_C)$. $\Delta_i$ satisfying $\tilde{A}_i=B\Delta_iC$ exists if we choose:
$B$ as $\tilde{B}=\begin{bmatrix} u_1&u_2&\dots u_{r_B}\end{bmatrix}$ and $C$ as $\tilde{C}=\begin{bmatrix} v_1&v_2&\dots v_{r_C}\end{bmatrix}^T$ where $u_i$ are the columns of $U_B$ and $v_i$ are the columns of $U_C$. We also need to meet $\lVert \Delta_i \rVert_2\leq1$. Therefore we need a scaling which is done as follows: Let: 
$\tilde{\Sigma}_B=diag(\sigma^b_1,\dots, \sigma^b_{r_B})$ and $\tilde{\Sigma}_C=diag(\sigma^c_1,\dots, \sigma^c_{r_C})$ and choose $B’=\tilde{B}\tilde{\Sigma}_B$ and  $C’=\tilde{C}\tilde{\Sigma}_C$ as the first scaling (why?). In $\tilde{A}_i=B\Delta_iC, i=1,\dots,N$ substitute $B$ and $C$ with $B’$ and $C’$ and solve for $\Delta_i$ for all $i$ and find $\kappa=\max_i \lVert\Delta_i \rVert$ (does the solution alway exist?). Then, choose: 
$B=\sqrt{\kappa}B'$ and $C=\sqrt{\kappa}C'$.

Comment: What does $\dot{x}=A_ix$ mean? Are you summing over $i$? As written, the subscript has been provided no context.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: No, I am not summing over $i$. The system has the form of $\dot{x}=A(p)x$ where $p$ is a vector of  parameters where each entry is  taking values in a bounded interval for example. I have N realization of $A(p)$ given as $A_i$, $i=1,\cdots,N$.

Comment: Are there any additional properties of the matrices (?) $B, \Delta_i, C$? What size are are they supposed to have? How is $N$ related to these sizes? If $N$ is small, compared to the number of entries in $B,C and \Delta_i$, a solution will not be unique.

Comment: There is no additional properties and I think the solution is not unique.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that $B$ and $C$ should be fixed for all $i$? If this is the case, I doubt that such a representation might generally exist.

Comment: Yes, $B$ and $C$ should be the same for all $i$.

Comment: Sorry, the requirement on $\Delta_i$is that $\rVert \Delta_i\lVert_2 \leq 1$ (not $=1$).